# What information does Pytorch nn.functional.interpolate use?

Tags: python, pytorch, interpolation

I have a tensor `img` in PyTorch of size `bx2xhxw` and want to upsample it using `torch.nn.functional.interpolate`. But while interpolation I do not wish channel 1 to use information from channel 2. To do this should I do,

```
img2 = torch.rand(b,2,2*h,2*w) # create a random torch tensor.
img2[:,0,:,:] = nn.functional.interpolate(img[:,0,:,:], [2*h,2*w], mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
img2[:,1,:,:] = nn.functional.interpolate(img[:,1,:,:], [2*h,2*w], mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
img=img2
```

or simply using

```
img = nn.functional.interpolate(img, [2*h,2*w], mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
```

will solve my purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use (2). There is no communication in the first and second dimensions (batch and channel respectively) for all types of interpolation (1D, 2D, 3D), as they should be.

Simple example:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

b = 2
c = 4
h = w = 8

a = torch.randn((b, c, h, w))
a_upsample = F.interpolate(a, [h*2, w*2], mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)

a_mod = a.clone()
a_mod[:, 0] *= 1000
a_mod_upsample = F.interpolate(a_mod, [h*2, w*2], mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)

print(torch.isclose(a_upsample[:,0], a_mod_upsample[:,0]).all())
print(torch.isclose(a_upsample[:,1], a_mod_upsample[:,1]).all())
print(torch.isclose(a_upsample[:,2], a_mod_upsample[:,2]).all())
print(torch.isclose(a_upsample[:,3], a_mod_upsample[:,3]).all())
```

Output:

```py
tensor(False)
tensor(True)
tensor(True)
tensor(True)
```

One can tell that a large change in the first channel has no effect in other channels.